# 404 on routing with nginx and expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, amazon-ec2, express-generator

i have created on EC2 an instance of ubuntu server and trying to get the express generator simple skeleton get working.
when i go to root http://MY_SERVER_IP_HERE/ the index page of the app is shown.
if i go to http://MY_SERVER_IP_HERE/users im getting 404 even though the express app is set up to handle this route.

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
```

/routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
/**** WORKS FINE ****/
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

/routes/users.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
/*** GETTING 404 ****/
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

module.exports = router;
```

my nginx routing settings:

```
location ~ ^/(stylesheets/|css/|js/){
    root /var/www/html/test/myapp/public;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://MY_SERVER_IP:3000;
}
```

thank you very much!

Comment: Is http://MY_SERVER_IP_HERE/users/ (with a slash at the end) working?

Answer (score 0):

Change the code like this.

**server.js**

```
var express= require('express');
var app = express();  
require('./routes/index')(app, express);
require('./routes/users')(app, express);
//.....
app.listen(3000);
```

**/routes/index.js**

```
module.exports  = function(app, express) {
    var router = express.Router();
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
        res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
    });
    app.use('/', router);
};
```

**/routes/users.js**

```
module.exports  = function(app, express) {
    var router = express.Router();
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
        res.send('respond with a resource');
    });
    app.use('/users', router);
};
```

Comment: sorry for some reason i still get 404, i will debug it over again and update on any changes